# How can I verify the value of a parameter being passed into a mocked function using Pester

Tags: powershell, unit-testing, mocking, pester-5

I have a function written in PowerShell and I am trying to test that function using Pester v-5. I have included the function under test and the Pester test case in the code samples below.

I am trying to verify that the parameter `$FileName` being passed into the mocked function `Save-Report` is correct. How can I do that?

**Notes:**

- I realise the value of that `$Filename` parameter is being set to a test value when I mock the function `Add-StringToFileName` and return a test value. But I still want to test that the value makes it down to the end and remains unchanged.
- This is definitely something that I would like to do in future tests so I want to understand how it can be done.

**Function under test**

```
Function Invoke-ReportDownloader
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        # The command object used to connect to the database
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Data.Odbc.OdbcCommand]$Command,

        # An XML element containing the report item to be retrieved
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Xml.XmlElement]$ReportItem,

        # Hashtable containing the configuration parameters
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [hashtable]$ConfigParams,

        # The SEMO participant that the report is being downloaded for
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Data.DataRow]$Participant
    )

    # If report is not supported jump to next report
    $ReportName = $ReportItem.ReportName
    if (-not (Test-ReportSupported $Command $ReportName)) {
        $Logger.Warning("Report: $($ReportName) is not currently supported")
        return
    }

    # (Kanban-7940) If there is no date included in the specified file name in
    # the report item then we append the associated date to the filename. This
    # is to avoid multiple reports of the same type overwriting each other.
    $Filename = $ReportItem.FileName
    if (-not (Test-TimestampIncluded -Filename $Filename)) {
        $FileName = Add-StringToFileName -Path $Filename -SubString $ReportItem.Date
    }

    # If report already exists in database jump to next report
    if (Test-MarketReportInDatabase $Command $ReportItem) {
        return
    }

    Get-Report $ConfigParams $Participant $ReportItem

    # If the response contains failure information throw an exception
    $ReportSuccessParams = @{
        ResponsePath = $ConfigParams.BmResponsePath
        BaseName = $ConfigParams.ReportFilter
    }
    if (-not (Test-SuccessfulResponse @ReportSuccessParams)) {
        throw "Unsuccessful response from BM"
    }

    $SaveReportParams = @{
        RawPath = $ConfigParams.RawPath
        XmlResponsePath = $ConfigParams.XmlResponsePath
        Filename = $FileName
    }
    Save-Report @SaveReportParams
}
```

**Unit tests**

```
Describe 'Invoke-ReportDownloader' {
    BeforeAll {
        # Set up test $Cmd object
        # Set up test $Logger object
        # Set up test $ReportItem object
        # Set up test $ConfigParams object
    }

    Context "No timestamp included in the filename" {

        BeforeAll {
            Mock Test-ReportSupported { return $true }
            Mock Test-MarketReportInDatabase { return $false }
            Mock Get-Report
            Mock Test-SuccessfulResponse { return $true }
            Mock Save-Report
        }

        BeforeEach {
            $Script:ReportDownloaderParams = @{
                Command = $Script:Cmd
                ReportItem = $ReportItem
                ConfigParams = $Script:ConfigParams
                Participant = $Script:Participant
            }
        }

        It "Should save the report with the timestamp included in the filename" {
            $TestFileName = "test_string_20210101"
            Mock Add-StringToFileName { return $TestFileName }
            Invoke-ReportDownloader @Script:ReportDownloaderParams
            Should -InvokeVerifiable Save-Report
            # I want to verify here that the parameter $FileName being passed into the mocked function Save-Report is correct.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can confirm a mock was called with specific parameters as follows:

```
Should -Invoke -CommandName Save-Report -Times 1 -ParameterFilter { $Filename -eq "test_string_20210101" }
```

See https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/usage/mocking#example for more details.

Comment: Thanks for that @mclayton. The solution is working. Interestingly enough though, if I change the test string in the -ParameterFilter the test fails (as expected) but the failure reason is unexpected (i.e. `Expected Save-Report to be called 1 times exactly but was called 0 times),

I assume that's because it is expecting the mocked function to be called with that exact parameter and if the parameter is different it treats it as the function not being called?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. If you don't case *what* parameters were used and you only want to check how many times it was called you can remove the ```-ParameterFilter ...```. And if you want to check for multiple calls with different parameters each time you can add multiple ```Should``` asserts with different parameter filters.